# ETh stuck in contract

Tags: contract-development

I modified the example crowd sale contract from the Ethereum site slightly. 
First I sent 0.5 ETH from a wallet, it then sent the new tokens and I ran the safeWithdrawal function as the Beneficiary. This then triggered the contract to send the 0.5 ETH to the Beneficiary. I then later sent 1 ETH to the contract and it sent the tokens. I then ran the safeWithdrawal function again as the Beneficiary on the contract but for some reason this time it did not send the 1 ETH. Does it have anything to do with the "if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised))" that it is wrapped in, what is that part even doing?

```
    function safeWithdrawal() {
    if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
        if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
            FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
        } else {
            //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
            fundingGoalReached = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think I know the problem, amountRaised increases each time, where I have withdraw .5 ETH it never took this off the amountRaised. So now there is 1 ETH but it is trying to withdraw 1.5 ETH. I guess I'm never going to get that back then?

Comment: It's hard to say seeing only this part of contracts. Please post the full code or link to your repository.

Comment: Are you resetting `amountRaised`? That not being reset can lead to the contract trying to send a larger amount than it has.

Comment: @OmkarKhair yeh thats the problem, amountRaised is 1.5 ETH but there is only 1ETH in the contract. That 1 ETH is stuck in the contract now isn't it

Comment: @MikeYoung you might be able to withdraw the ETH, can you please share the full contract code to evaluate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with my version... the answer is to deploy a force send contract that forward funds sent to it and then immediately self destructs.

I used this to rescue some eth from mine.

`contract ForceSend {
  function ForceSend(address recipient) payable {
    selfdestruct(recipient);
  }
}`

You need to send enough to make amountRaised match the balance

Comment: Would that still work even though I didn't include a ForceSend function in the contract? As in is ForceSend built into solidity already?

Comment: you are creating the forceSend function in the new contract.  Try it.  Worked for me.

Comment: execute forceSend on the new contract and send 0.5 eth.  Check it is received by the stuck contract. Then execute checkGoalReached and safeWithdrawal on the stuck contract.  Job done.

Comment: Check this tx for proof.  I forwarded the difference to this address, it then forwards the funds and immediatley self destructs so the funds cant come back.  The eth is then stuck in the jammed contract and hasnt raised amountRaised because it didnt call the payable function.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf59679e3e256ba89b08d30ac6a0e6f728e84ba56f799135268e1a04fe18c382e

Comment: How would this new contract help? It's a new contract and it can't access Ether in another contract.